# Glm quaternion slerp

Tags: c++, opengl

I am trying to do slerp using quaternions in glm. 
I am using

```
glm::quat interpolatedquat = quaternion::mix(quat1,quat2,0.5f)
```

These are the libraries I added

```
#include <glm/gtc/quaternion.hpp>
#include <glm/gtx/quaternion.hpp>
#include <glm/gtx/euler_angles.hpp>
#include <glm/gtx/norm.hpp>
#include <glm\glm.hpp>
#include <glm\glm\glm.hpp>
using namespace glm;
```

But I can't get it to work. I added all the glm quaternion .hpp's

The error is "quaternion" must be a classname or namespace.

Comment: "can't get it to work"...is it segfaulting?  Deleting your home directory?

Comment: @genpfault hey man sorry Added the error I am getting

Comment: @genpfault I tried glm:: but it doesn't seem to fix it

Comment: good of you that you use a float as last parameter, otherwise there's errors

Answer (score 13, accepted):

A search of all files in GLM 0.9.4.6 for `namespace quaternion` or `quaternion::` yields only a single line in `gtc/quaternion.hpp` which has been commented out.  All public GLM functionality is implemented directly in the `glm` namespace.  Implementation details exist in `glm::detail` and occasionally `glm::_detail`, but you should never use anything in these namespaces directly, as they are subject to change in future versions.

Subnamespaces for each module/extension are not used.  Therefore, you just need:

```
glm::quat interpolatedquat = glm::mix(quat1,quat2,0.5f)
```

And you probably want a semicolon at the end there.

**Edit:** You will also probably also want to use `glm::slerp` instead of `glm::mix` as it has an extra check to ensure that the shortest path is taken:

```
// If cosTheta < 0, the interpolation will take the long way around the sphere. 
// To fix this, one quat must be negated.
if (cosTheta < T(0))
{
    z        = -y;
    cosTheta = -cosTheta;
}
```

This is not present in the `mix` version, which is otherwise identical.